# Existence of Moments

Tags: self-study, mean, expected-value, moments

$X$ is a random variable with probability density function $$f(x) = \frac{c}{(1+x^2)^m}$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $m \geq 1$, and $c = \frac{\Gamma{(m)}}{\left[\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\Gamma{ \left(m- \frac{1}{2}\right)} \right]^m}$. Show that $E\left[X^{2r}\right]$ exists if and only if $2r<2m-1.$

I am completely clueless as I can't integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c |x^{2r}|}{(1+x^2)^m}dx.$$

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and tell us more about what you tried.

Comment: You don't actually need to compute that integral.  You only need to ascertain whether it converges.  To that end, it is useful to know that the integral of the function $x\to |x|^\alpha$ converges if and only if $\alpha \lt -1$.  Compare the integrand to functions of this sort.